# Clone of an old bare repository appears empty

Tags: git

I'm trying to recover some files from a backup of an old, bare, git repository which was originally managed using Tortoise Git in Windows (if that makes any difference) but when I clone it on my Mac I get the message:

> warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

I understand this warning but I do not believe this repository *is* empty. I've been trying to learn more about the way git works but I don't seem to be getting anywhere, this is where I need your help.

Looking at the files in the "remote" (it's actually sitting on an external HDD) repository there are the following files/folders; what makes me think the repository is not actually empty is because the `objects` folder contains 161 sub folders, about 87MB of data:

[image: remote repository folders]

The contents of the `master` file is a checksum (I'm guessing) that (I think) points to the head of the `master` branch. However, running the command `git branch -a` returns nothing.

I also tried using `gitk --all` but that gives the error:

> Error parsing revisions: unknown revision HEAD

I looked in to repairing a git repository and that lead me to try creating a new repo, copying the `.pack` files in and unpacking them with `git unpack-objects < my.pack`. This created a load of folders/files in the `objects` folder but still commands such as `git branch` and `git checkout` fail.

Can anyone suggest a way to get at the the files in the `objects` folder?

**Some more info**

Here's the command line output when I clone the project and then try to use it:

```
$ mkdir project
$ git init project
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/tony/git/project/.git/
$ cd project/
$ git clone /Volumes/Backup/git/db/reporting
Cloning into 'reporting'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ git branch -a
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

The result of the `branch` command is nothing and the checkout results in an error. I recognise the 'Initial commit' message as that's what I usually use when I first add files to a new repo.

I've tried unpacking the files in to a new repo, here's the command line output of that process:

```
$ mkdir unpack
$ git init unpack/
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/tony/git/unpack/.git/
$ cd unpack/
$ git unpack-objects < /Volumes/Backup/git/db/reporting/objects/pack/pack-9e157880d61b9a9cecba012130de16cc71f898b5.pack
Unpacking objects: 100% (185/185), done.
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ git branch
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

The next thing I tried was to add a simple text file to the repo, this managed to reinstate the `master` branch:

```
$ pico readme
$ ls
readme
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    readme

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'added a file'
[master (root-commit) 3ec34b9] added a file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 readme
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git branch
* master
$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
```

The addition of a new file has enabled me to see the branch again but unfortunately I'm still unable to recover the files from the objects folder.

In response to Vorac's comment, here's the output when I don't create a repo first:

```
$ git clone /Volumes/Backup/git/db/reporting
Cloning into 'reporting'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
$ ls
reporting
$ cd reporting/
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
$ git show
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

The contents of the `config` file

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
```

As suggested by [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5032339/roman) I ran the `fsck` command on a copy of the respoitory, here's the output:

```
$ git fsck --full
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
```

Comment: Weird. What does `git status` report?

Comment: @Vorac - in a repo cloned from the old one (not the one I unpacked objects in)  it says "On branch master" with one comment "Initial commit". In the repo I unpacked files in it says "Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone. (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)". I'll give that a go and report what happens.

Comment: You shouldn't create a repository, before cloning. I.e. you should do 1. `cd` to a folder, that is NOT inside a git repo 2. run `git clone` 3. inspect what happened `git status`, `git log`, `git show`.

Comment: @Vorac - I've updated the question with the command line output doing what you suggest. I've a bad feeling I'm not going to be able to recover anything from this old repo :)

Comment: What happens when you take that hex string (SHA1) from `refs/heads/master` and run `git show that-hex-string`? And can you show the contents of `config` file? Also, try this with that pack file: `git verify-pack -v /path/to/pack.idx` (notice the `.idx` extension instead of `.pack`) - it should list the objects found inside the pack.

Comment: @Roman - The `git show` reports `fatal: bad object 0a58b515701dfb7f5bd446a9b954dcf31547210d` when I run the command from the repo on the backup drive. `config` file contents added to the question but the output of the `verify-pack` was too long, so I've put it in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hDzr6bMx)

Comment: Looks like the repository is broken, because some files are missing. You should copy the entire repository folder somewhere else and run `git fsck --full` inside it, it will tell you how bad things are. After that you can try to inspect some of the commits reported by `git verify-pack`, maybe there is still something useful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Roman. I've added the output from the `fsck` command to the question. I've not had a chance to explore the other commits listed by `verify-pack`. As you say, I think the chances of me getting any files back is pretty slim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a double repository - your bare repository is a working copy of an empty non-bare repository. I don't know if your file manager shows hidden files, but you should look for a `.git` folder inside your bare repository folder (using `ls -al`, for example); also you can confirm this by running `git status` inside the bare repository - if I'm right, it will print something like the following:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   HEAD
#   config
#   description
#   hooks/
#   info/
#   refs/
#
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

If it is the case, you should separate the two - move `.git` folder somewhere (or just copy the repository and delete `.git` from copy).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! You were correct, there was a `.git` repo hiding in the folder. I copied the all the files, removed the `.git` folder, and then cloned the repository. No errors displayed and the files from the repository appeared.